# Mybatis - Invalid bound statement (not found)

Tags: spring-boot, mybatis

I have created a new project using mybatis to connect to a mysql database. This is my second project using mybatis so I am familiar with it but am getting the following error when I call the save method:

```
2019-03-05 10:08:01.031 ERROR 86438 --- [nio-9905-exec-1] c.q.f.r.c.ResolveRestController          : Error starting preset: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis.mapper.ResolveJobReportMapper.saveResolveJobReport
org.apache.ibatis.binding.BindingException: Invalid bound statement (not found): com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis.mapper.ResolveJobReportMapper.saveResolveJobReport
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod$SqlCommand.<init>(MapperMethod.java:232) ~[mybatis-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.<init>(MapperMethod.java:50) ~[mybatis-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.lambda$cachedMapperMethod$0(MapperProxy.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660) ~[na:1.8.0_101]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.cachedMapperMethod(MapperProxy.java:62) ~[mybatis-3.5.0.jar:3.5.0]**
 ...
```

My mybatis config file is as follows (in src/main/resources):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration
PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN"
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">

<configuration>
    <settings>
        <!-- changes from the defaults -->
       <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
       <!-- Mybatis logging -->
       <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J2"/>
    </settings>
    <typeAliases>
        <package name="com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis.domain"/>

    </typeAliases>
    
   <mappers>
      <mapper resource="mapper/ResolveJobReport.xml"/>
<!--       <mapper resource="com/qlsdistribution/fps/resolverender/data/mybatis/mapper/ResolveJobReport.xml"/> -->
   </mappers>
</configuration>
```

As you can see I have tried different locations for the mapper xml file but if I put invalid syntax in the mapper xml file, it fails with invalid syntax (SAXParseException) instead so I know the mapper xml file is being read.

The mapper xml file is as follows (in src/main/resources/mapper):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis.ResolveJobReportMapper">

    <resultMap id="resolveJobReport" type="com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis.domain.ResolveJobReport">
        <result property="id" column="id" />
        <result property="fpsProjectName" column="fps_project_name" />
        <result property="inputPath" column="input_path" />
        <result property="destinationPath" column="destination_path" />
        <result property="presetName" column="preset_name" />
        <result property="ipAddress" column="ip_address" />
        <result property="frameRate" column="frame_rate" />
        <result property="resolveProjectName" column="resolve_project_name" />
        <result property="width" column="width" />
        <result property="height" column="height" />
        <result property="renderFormat" column="render_format" />
        <result property="renderCodec" column="render_codec" />
        <result property="scriptPath" column="script_path" />
        <result property="cliOutput" column="cli_output" />
        <result property="jobStartedDate" column="job_started_date" />
        <result property="jobFinishedDate" column="job_finished_date" />
        <result property="createdBy" column="created_by" />
        <result property="createdDate" column="created_date" />
        <result property="modifiedBy" column="modified_by" />
        <result property="modifiedDate" column="modified_date" />
    </resultMap>
    
    <select id="getAllResolveJobReports" resultMap="resolveJobReport">
        SELECT id, fps_project_name, input_path, destination_path, preset_name, ip_address, frame_rate, resolve_project_name, width, height, 
        render_format, render_codec, script_path, cli_output, job_started_date, job_finished_date, created_by, created_date, modified_by, modified_date
        FROM resolve_job_report
        WHERE fps_setting_id = #{value}
        ORDER by id desc;
    </select>
    
    <select id="getAllResolveJobReportsById" parameterType="Long"  resultMap="resolveJobReport">
        SELECT id, fps_project_name, input_path, destination_path, preset_name, ip_address, frame_rate, resolve_project_name, width, height, 
        render_format, render_codec, script_path, cli_output, job_started_date, job_finished_date, created_by, created_date, modified_by, modified_date
        FROM resolve_job_report
        WHERE id = #{value};
    </select>
    
    <insert id="saveResolveJobReport" parameterType="com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis.domain.ResolveJobReport">
        INSERT INTO resolve_job_report 
        (fps_project_name, input_path, destination_path, preset_name, ip_address, frame_rate, resolve_project_name, width, height, 
        render_format, render_codec, script_path, cli_output, job_started_date, job_finished_date, created_by)
        VALUE 
        (#{fpsProjectName},#{inputPath},#{destinationPath},#{presetName},#{ipAddress},#{frameRate},#{resolveProjectName},#{width},#{height},
        #{renderFormat},#{renderCodec}, #{scriptPath},#{cliOutput},#{jobStartedDate},#{jobFinishedDate},#{createdBy});
    </insert>

    <update id="updateResolveJobReportById" parameterType="resolveJobReport">
        UPDATE resolve_job_report
        SET
        fps_project_name = #{fpsProjectName}, 
        input_path = #{inputPath}, 
        destination_path = #{destinationPath}, 
        preset_name = #{presetName}, 
        ip_address = #{ipAddress}, 
        frame_rate = #{frameRate}, 
        resolve_project_name = #{resolveProjectName}, 
        width = #{width}, 
        height = #{height}, 
        render_format = #{renderFormat}, 
        render_codec = #{renderCodec}, 
        script_path = #{scriptPath}, 
        cli_output = #{cliOutput}, 
        job_started_date = #{jobStartedDate}, 
        job_finished_date = #{jobFinishedDate},
        modified_by = #{modifiedBy}
        where id = #{id};
    </update>
   
    <delete id="deleteResolveJobReporttById" parameterType="Long">
        DELETE FROM resolve_job_report
        WHERE id = #{value}
    </delete>
</mapper>
```

My application.properties file contains the following (in (src/main/resources):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fpsresolvetool?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:schema.sql

mybatis.config-location=classpath:SqlMapConfig.xml
```

I have even tried using the latest mybatis versions in my pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis -->
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
     <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
     <version>3.5.0</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis-spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

My spring boot application is as follows:

```java
    @SpringBootApplication
    @EnableScheduling
    @ComponentScan({"com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender"})
    @EnableJms
    @MapperScan("com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis")
    public class FPSResolveRenderApp implements WebMvcConfigurer {
        /** UTF-8 Character set name */
        private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";
        
        /** Logger */
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(FPSResolveRenderApp.class);
        
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            new SpringApplicationBuilder(FPSResolveRenderApp.class).run(args);
            
        }
    
        /**
         * Creates and gets the FilterRegistrationBean
         * @return
         */
        @Bean
        public FilterRegistrationBean<CharacterEncodingFilter> filterRegistrationBean() {
            FilterRegistrationBean<CharacterEncodingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<CharacterEncodingFilter>();
            CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
            characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding(UTF_8);
            registrationBean.setFilter(characterEncodingFilter);
            return registrationBean;
        }
    }
```

The mapper interface is as follows:

```java
    @Mapper
    public interface ResolveJobReportMapper {
    
        public List<ResolveJobReport> getAllResolveJobReports();
        
        public List<ResolveJobReport> getAllResolveJobReports(RowBounds rowBounds);
        
        public List<ResolveJobReport> getAllResolveJobReportsById(Long id);
        
        public List<ResolveJobReport> getAllResolveJobReportsById(Long id, RowBounds rowBounds);
        
        public void saveResolveJobReport(ResolveJobReport resolveJobReport);
    
        public void updateResolveJobReportById(ResolveJobReport resolveJobReport);
    
        public void deleteResolveJobReporttById(Long id);
    
    }
```

And the service class is as follows:

```java
    @Service("ResolveJobReportService")
    public class ResolveJobReportService {
    
        @Autowired
        private ResolveJobReportMapper resolveJobReportMapper= null;
        
        public List<ResolveJobReport> getAllResolveJobReports() {
            return resolveJobReportMapper.getAllResolveJobReports();
        }
        
        public List<ResolveJobReport> getAllResolveJobReports(RowBounds rowBounds) {
            return resolveJobReportMapper.getAllResolveJobReports();
        }
         
        public List<ResolveJobReport> getAllResolveJobReportsById(Long id) {
            return resolveJobReportMapper.getAllResolveJobReportsById(id);
        }
        
        public List<ResolveJobReport> getAllResolveJobReportsById(Long id, RowBounds rowBounds) {
            return resolveJobReportMapper.getAllResolveJobReportsById(id);
        }
    
        public void saveResolveJobReport(ResolveJobReport resolveJobReport) {
            resolveJobReportMapper.saveResolveJobReport(resolveJobReport);
        }
    
        public void updateResolveJobReportById(ResolveJobReport resolveJobReport) {
            resolveJobReportMapper.updateResolveJobReportById(resolveJobReport);
        }
    
        public void deleteResolveJobReporttById(Long id) {
            resolveJobReportMapper.deleteResolveJobReporttById(id);
        }
        
    }
```

Can anyone see what is wrong.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem happens because the `namespace` in mapper xml is `com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis.ResolveJobReportMapper` but the package the mapper interface is `com.qlsdistribution.fps.resolverender.data.mybatis.mapper.ResolveJobReportMapper`.

To fix it make sure they match.

Answer (score 4):

Put it in application.properties `mybatis.mapper-locations=classpath*:**/mappers/*Mapper.xml`

Comment: my problem was that I added this to the properties file but there was an extra space before abates keyword and that made a problem. Im using Gradle and not maven

Answer (score 2):

I hit this problem recenly, and checked everything that can be found in the internet. Cost me a whole day.

Finally I put the `xml` files in the same place with the interface java files, which solved the problem.

I think that is because for some reasons the xml files can not be found, and putting them there make them visiable.

Comment: Or put xml files in `Resources` folder under the same package structure as your interface java files. Maven's `process-resources` phase will automatically place them together while building the project. This will make the code base a lot cleaner

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message when I changed my project from a JavaFX Project to a Maven Project.

I had to move all my xml mapper files to the resource folder. After that, worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

for me the fix was giving same filename for both the java (mapper interface class) and corresponding xml file

Answer (score 1):

For those people using MyBatis without xml in spring boot project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis.spring.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Please check your spring boot application class, make sure your `@MapperScan` matches your `dao` package.

```
@MapperScan("com.jjs.videoservice.dao")
```

The path must be SAME as your dao package (contains your mapper interface), I ignored "dao" and caused the issue.

Hope it helps someone, thanks

Comment: This is equivalent to adding `@Mapper` on top of interface which OP already did.

Answer (score 0):

I had 2 mappers in the same package. It was the root cause of the problem. Once each mapper interface was moved to separate package, the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I used the same name for mapper and java class but the mapping in mapper.xml was pointing to the wrong java class

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem recently, I noticed, that I added the new method in the production xml mapper file by mistake and not in the actual xml mappers in resources folder. Once the actual xml mappers in resources folder was updated, it fixed the problem. So please make sure you update the right mapper files in your src folder that gets compiled.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes people do this mistake:

In **resources** folder the created folder like "`org.my_app.mybatis`", but the correct way is do separate folder for each part of  package

```
-org
--my_app
---mybatis
```

It is hard to recognize when you do it in code editor.
Visually we have the same result

[image]

**But actually a different structure**
[image]

**Green** will work, **red** - won't.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem same and there is a method maybe can help you.

when you create a package in resources, don't just use the below method simply
`com.mybatis.mapper`

[image]

- you shold step by step to create it
- or you can use  `\` to instead of `.`
  like`com\mybatis\mapper`

[image]